# jQuery - Form Validation Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have one form on this page: http://www.chatspring.me/FitTracker/.

It's not working, and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you're including jQuery twice--once before including validate and once after.

If I remove the jQuery include in the `body` tag, everything works fine.  This is probably because the validate plugin is being attached to the first jQuery instance that's loaded, but then the second time you include jQuery, the validate plugin is being wiped away.

Here's your code working (minus styling): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/5kEbX/